# Send NodeJS variable to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I would like to send variable (name) from NodeJS to HTML/JS on page loading (to get res parameter in HTML).
But my code isn't working:

NodeJS part:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const directoryToServe = 'client';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client')));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("index", { name: "example" });
});
```

HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course, I have installed Handlebars.
Thank you very much
Nathan

Comment: Do you get an error of some sort?

Comment: Not in browser console, and in NodeJS console, it just write "{{ name }}"

Comment: Having it installed is not enough, it should be configured to be used by Express. The code shows that it isn't.

Comment: Have you any example code of how to configure it ? Thank you :)

Comment: This link should help: https://www.kulik.io/2018/01/02/how-to-use-handlebars-with-express/

Comment: I don't. Did you try to use search 'express handlebars' before posting? I'm positive the first link in google is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't imported `express-handlebars` or configured the Render Engine.

Example below:

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Good luck!